# Unable to reach WCF rest endpoint by post

Tags: wcf, rest, soap, azure, unity-container

I'm trying to create a WCF service hosted in an Azure web role. The service must be able to be reachable by soap and rest.

I've been reading some articles and was able to create (or at least I thought so) a service with all the specifications.

What I'm trying to do is to consume my rest endpoint with a SoapUI project, doing a POST with the querystring with all the parameters, but when I run this project the response I get is:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'CPlano'. The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).'

Here is a part of my Web.Config:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize ="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="50000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="500000000" maxArrayLength="500000000" maxBytesPerRead="500000000"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="500000000" maxStringContentLength="500000000"/>
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Namespace.CService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint name="RESTEnpoint" contract="Namespace.ICService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" bindingNamespace="http://www.example.com/" address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" />
    <endpoint name="SOAPEndpoint" contract="Namespace.ICService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://www.example.com/" address=""></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Also here is my service interface declaration:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/")]
public interface ICService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/CPlano",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    Method = "POST")]
    RespuestaCotizador CPlano(int idUsuario, string usuario, string pass, int modalidad, int servicio,
        int medicion, string paisDestino, int envio, decimal peso, decimal largo, decimal ancho, decimal alto);
}
```

And finally my response class:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/")]
public class RespuestaCotizador
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool HasError;
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessageESP;
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessageENG;
    [DataMember]
    public decimal PrecioCotizado;

    public RespuestaCotizador()
    {
        HasError = false;
        ErrorMessageESP = string.Empty;
        ErrorMessageENG = string.Empty;
        PrecioCotizado = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm using unity for dependency injection, but this seems to be non relevant.

Even when I'm running the service locally I can reach even the first breakpoint.

Comment: Given the exception message you are seeing I wonder if SoapUI is correctly setting up the call to the service.  WCF is receiving the message and is attempting to change the incoming message to the CPlano object, but is failing because it thinks the message doesn't contain any information.  Have you tried using the WCFTestClient.exe that comes with Visual Studio or even a separate project to test your service yet?  Something other than SoapUI to rule out the SoapUI being the issue?

Also, attempt to run the web project outside the emulator (set it as startup project) to rule out Azure.

Comment: Hi! I have tried with the WCFTestClient...but I think it only call the service with the soap endpoint...with this tool I received a correct answer from the service.

Comment: Yes, you and Ming Xu are right, the WCFTest client doesn't test the REST endpoint, but if the SOAP endpoint answers correctly then you have ruled out a problem with the service itself, and now you are down to looking at the the REST endpoint or the caller being the problem.  What happens when you use a different tool (fiddler like Ming suggested, or even another project)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use SOAP or REST? If you want to use SOAP, then use another binding, such as BasicHttpBinding. WebHttpBinding is usually used for REST services. If you want to use REST, you can create a class that encapsulates everything like idUsuario and usuario. Config the service method to accept a single parameter: Your new class. Then when doing a POST, you pass a serialized object as the request body. In addition, you cannot use WCF test client to consume a REST service. It only stands by SOAP. You can, however, use Fiddler. Alternatively (and recommended for new services), use ASP.NET Web API instead of WCF to build REST services.